# iOS: Passing parsed values from soap webservice in NSObject class back to UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, soap, nsobject

I don't know why this is being so difficult but I can't get this to work. Here's my simple problem:

I have a `UIViewController` that calls paring class type of `NSObject` class that does the parsing jobs.

I just need the parsed data values to be returned back to that `ViewController`.

Could any body provide me a simple step or any suggestion to do this...
I really need this issue to be solved for my project and the deadline is near...

Thanks
Here is my code:

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    wsClass *ws = [[wsClass alloc] init];
    [ws initParsing];
}
```

wsClass.h

```
@interface ProjListClass : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString * PROJECT_ID;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString * SHORT_DESCR;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString * LOCATION;
@end;

@interface wsClass : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>{
ProjListClass *proj_obj;
ProjListClass *prj;

NSMutableData* webData;
NSMutableString *soapResults;
NSURLConnection *conn;

NSXMLParser *xmlParser;

}
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray * arrHouses;
@property(nonatomic, strong)     NSXMLParser *xmlParser;

-(void) initParsing;
@end
```

wsClass.m

```
#import "wsClass.h"

@implementation ProjListClass
@synthesize PROJECT_ID, SHORT_DESCR, LOCATION;
@end

@implementation wsClass

@synthesize arrHouses, xmlParser;

-(void) initParsing{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    arrHouses=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<Projects_List xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"/>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n"];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.10:8056/WServices.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/Projects_List" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if( conn )
{
    webData = [NSMutableData data];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}   
}
....
....
....
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (xmlParser)
  {
    xmlParser=nil;
  }
  xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
  [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
  [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
  [xmlParser parse];
 }

 ....
 ....
 ....
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
.....
.....
.....
 else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"ProjectsListDetails"])
{
    [arrHouses addObject:proj_obj];
    proj_obj=nil;
}

soapResults = nil;
soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
}
```

Comment: Just Simple return the value from that class using function :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below Steps would give you some idea

**1)** Inside the Your NSOBject Class say `ParsingModel` class, Create Protocol Inside that parsing Class where you doing parsing. give name whatever you want.

```
   @protocol  WebServiceResponseDelegate <NSObject>

   @optional
  - (void)didRecieveResponseData:(NSMutableArray*)array;

  @end
```

Implement this protocol to the Parsing Class like this 
   `@protocol  WebServiceResponseDelegate;`

Create Property Inside the Parsing Class so that could set the `Delegate` from confirming class..

```
      @property   (nonatomic, assign) id<WebServiceResponseDelegate>delegate;
```

and Just need to send the Parsed Data To the Confirming Class i.e from where you created parsing object

```
   //say didRecieveResponse this is the method called when you completed parsing of data

 // - (void)didRecieveResponse
  // {   
  //  if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didRecieveResponseData)])
 //    {
  //    //pass populated dataSource which would have the Parsed Data.

  //    [delegate didRecieveResponseData:parsedData];
 //    //  parsedData is the NUMtableArray or any other DataSource.

  //}
```

**EDIT:** See below is the `delegate` method called when you finished the paring successfully

```
  - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    //pass populated dataSource which would have the Parsed Data.  

    //before check whether that delegate method confirmed by the class.

    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didRecieveResponseData)])
     {
       [delegate didRecieveResponseData:parsedData];
     }

   //  parsedData is the NUMtableArray or any other DataSource.

   }
  // called when the parser has completed parsing. If this is encountered, the parse was successful.you need to call
```

**2)** And Inside the Confirming Class as You said `UIViewController` say `DataViewController`
 define That delegate Method 
 in your `DataViewController.h` adopt that protocol like this `DataViewController<WebServiceResponse>`

And set `Delegate` from the point at where you creating the parsing model class
like this

```
  ParsingModel * paring = [ParsingModel alloc]init];
  [paring setWebServiceResponseDelegate:self];

 //definition of callback delegate method
 - (void)didRecieveResponseData:(NSMutableArray*)array
 {
 //here you would have the Parsed Data now you can use it as you want

 }
```

I hope everything clear to you.

Comment: thanks Kamarshad, I have edited my thread and pasted my code, could please have a look at it and tell me where to change in my code... Regards

Comment: its my current code that i'm using, tell how I can apply the protocol.

Comment: @Mr.KLD  See my edit, changed the code,.If still you don't understand then i can't help you further.actually here Over S/O we discuss the logic rather than provide whole running code.and what i think u looking for whole running code. man just look into the code and try to get some idea from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a protocol in your NSObject class, trigger it when all your parsing operations have finished and set your view controller as a delegate.